# How to prevent user from saving comma at integer field in whole Odoo system?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

I noticed that whenever you type comma in integer field, odoo (or python) automatically removes that comma and merges numbers (for example whenever you type 1,3 it will become 13). If I type 1.3 or 1;3 etc. everything is fine. Probably I could do something like @api.constrains for a field, but how I could fix this for whole system?

Thank you for your time considering my question.

Comment: I think you should find corresponding code in Odoo source code and change it, because python doesn't do this

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the language the user has chosen. Under `Settings/Translations/Languages` (in newer versions of Odoo you first need to activate developer mode to see this menu) chose a language and look into "Thousands Separator" and "Decimal Separator".

For example using German language it's the other way around, because we use comma as decimal separator and dot as thousands separator.

So nothing to program here, it's just a configuration issue.